# How to create Custom UI Date PickerViews in the same UIView in swift

Tags: ios, swift3, uiviewcontroller

Im trying to have two different date pickerViews on the same viewController and let them represent different data. I have tried a different ways to do this, but both date picker views showing same Data, but can't put it all together.I'm new to swift programming. Any help would be awesome!

```
 @IBOutlet weak var EventStart: UITextField!
var datepicker = UIDatePicker()
var datepicker2 = UIDatePicker()
@IBOutlet weak var EventEnd: UITextField!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    createDatePicker()
    Event.delegate = self
    eventName.delegate = self
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
func createDatePicker(){

    datepicker.datePickerMode = .dateAndTime
    datepicker2.datePickerMode = .dateAndTime
    let toolbar = UIToolbar()
    toolbar.sizeToFit()
    let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .done, target: nil, action: #selector(donePressed))
    toolbar.setItems([doneButton], animated: false)
    EventEnd.inputAccessoryView = toolbar
    EventEnd.inputView = datepicker2
    EventStart.inputAccessoryView = toolbar
    EventStart.inputView = datepicker
}

func donePressed(){
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateStyle = .medium
    dateFormatter.timeStyle = .none
    EventStart.text = dateFormatter.string(from: datepicker.date)
    EventEnd.text = dateFormatter.string(from: datepicker2.date)
    print(EventStart)
    print(EventEnd)
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@IBOutlet weak var EventStart: UITextField!
var datepicker = UIDatePicker()
var datepicker2 = UIDatePicker()
@IBOutlet weak var EventEnd: UITextField!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

   self.addDatePicker(datepicker, textfield:EventStart , selector: #selector(ViewController.donePressed))
    self.addDatePicker(datepicker2 , textfield:EventEnd ,selector: #selector(ViewController.donePressed2))

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}


func addDatePicker(_ datepicker : UIDatePicker, textfield: UITextField, selector: Selector) {


    let toolbar = UIToolbar()
    toolbar.sizeToFit()
    let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .done, target: nil, action:selector)
    toolbar.setItems([doneButton], animated: false)


    textfield.inputAccessoryView = toolbar
    textfield.inputView = datepicker

}

func donePressed(){
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateStyle = .medium
    dateFormatter.timeStyle = .none
    EventStart.text = dateFormatter.string(from: datepicker.date)
    print(EventStart)
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}

func donePressed2(){
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateStyle = .medium
    dateFormatter.timeStyle = .none
    EventEnd.text = dateFormatter.string(from: datepicker2.date)
    print(EventEnd)
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}
```

Comment: I am glad that I helped. You should check naming conventions, for example https://github.com/raywenderlich/swift-style-guide . If you start using them it is going lot simpler to you an other developers to understand your code.

Answer (score 0):

The simple thing is to create two separate method for two of em. Also do not initialized them on view load.

This is my code for doing it.

```
var objDatePickerFrom: UIDatePicker!
var objDatePickerTo: UIDatePicker!
```

Then on respective button tap, I init them as below (you also do this in textview's delegate method if you do not use buttons.)

```
@IBAction func btnFromDateTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    self.initDatePikerFrom(frame: self.view.frame)
}

@IBAction func btnToDateTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    self.initDatePikerTo(frame: self.view.frame)
}
```

Below are the methods for init the date pickers.

```
func  initDatePikerFrom(frame: CGRect)  {
    self.objDatePickerFrom = UIDatePicker()
    objDatePickerFrom.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    objDatePickerFrom.datePickerMode = .date
    if DeviceType.IS_IPHONE_4_OR_LESS
    {
        objDatePickerFrom?.frame.size = CGSize(width: frame.size.width, height: 150)
    }
    self.txtFromDate.inputView = objDatePickerFrom

    objDatePickerFrom.maximumDate = Date()

    if self.txtFromDate.text! != "" {
        objDatePickerFrom.date = CommonFunctions.getDate(date: self.txtFromDate.text!)
    }
    self.view.bringSubview(toFront: objDatePickerFrom)
    let numberToolbar = UIToolbar(frame: CGRect.init(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: frame.size.width, height: 40.0))
    numberToolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.default
    numberToolbar.barTintColor = NavigationBGColor
    numberToolbar.layer.borderColor = UIColor(red: 79.0/255.0, green: 157.0/255.0, blue: 191.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0).cgColor
    numberToolbar.layer.borderWidth = 0.0
    let lblSelect = UILabel(frame: CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 150, height: 30))
    lblSelect.text = "Select Date"
    lblSelect.textColor = WhiteFontColor
    lblSelect.textAlignment = .center

    let btnBarCancel = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Cancel", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: self, action: #selector(MyAccountViewController.btnCancelFromDateClick(_:)) )
    btnBarCancel.tintColor = WhiteFontColor

    let btnBarDone = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.done, target: self, action: #selector(MyAccountViewController.btnDoneFromDateClick(_:)) )
    btnBarDone.tintColor = WhiteFontColor

    numberToolbar.items = [
        btnBarCancel,
        UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil),
        UIBarButtonItem.init(customView: lblSelect),
        UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil),
        btnBarDone]
    numberToolbar.sizeToFit()
    self.txtFromDate.inputAccessoryView = numberToolbar
    self.txtFromDate.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    self.txtFromDate.delegate = self
    self.txtFromDate.becomeFirstResponder()
}

func  initDatePikerTo(frame: CGRect)  {
        self.objDatePickerTo = UIDatePicker()
        self.objDatePickerTo.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        self.objDatePickerTo.datePickerMode = .date
        if DeviceType.IS_IPHONE_4_OR_LESS
        {
            self.objDatePickerTo?.frame.size = CGSize(width: frame.size.width, height: 150)
        }
        self.txtToDate.inputView = self.objDatePickerTo

        self.objDatePickerTo.maximumDate = Date()

        if self.txtToDate.text! != "" {
            self.objDatePickerTo.date = CommonFunctions.getDate(date: self.txtToDate.text!)
        }
        self.view.bringSubview(toFront: self.objDatePickerTo)
        let numberToolbar = UIToolbar(frame: CGRect.init(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: frame.size.width, height: 40.0))
        numberToolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.default
        numberToolbar.barTintColor = NavigationBGColor
        numberToolbar.layer.borderColor = UIColor(red: 79.0/255.0, green: 157.0/255.0, blue: 191.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0).cgColor
        numberToolbar.layer.borderWidth = 0.0
        let lblSelect = UILabel(frame: CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 150, height: 30))
        lblSelect.text = "Select Date"
        lblSelect.textColor = WhiteFontColor
        lblSelect.textAlignment = .center

        let btnBarCancel = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Cancel", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: self, action: #selector(MyAccountViewController.btnCancelToDateClick(_:)) )
        btnBarCancel.tintColor = WhiteFontColor

        let btnBarDone = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.done, target: self, action: #selector(MyAccountViewController.btnDoneToDateClick(_:)) )
        btnBarDone.tintColor = WhiteFontColor

        numberToolbar.items = [
            btnBarCancel,
            UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil),
            UIBarButtonItem.init(customView: lblSelect),
            UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil),
            btnBarDone]
        numberToolbar.sizeToFit()
        self.txtToDate.inputAccessoryView = numberToolbar
        self.txtToDate.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        self.txtToDate.delegate = self
        self.txtToDate.becomeFirstResponder()
    }
```

The other related methods similar to your `donePressed()` are as below.

```
func btnDoneFromDateClick(_ sendre: AnyObject)
{
    let date = CommonFunctions.getStrDate(date: self.objDatePickerFrom.date)
    self.txtFromDate.text = "\(date.day) \(date.month) \(date.year)"
    self.txtFromDate.resignFirstResponder()
    self.txtFromDate.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
}

func btnDoneToDateClick(_ sendre: AnyObject)
{
    let date = CommonFunctions.getStrDate(date: self.objDatePickerTo.date)
    self.txtToDate.text = "\(date.day) \(date.month) \(date.year)"
    self.txtToDate.resignFirstResponder()
    self.txtToDate.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
}
```

May this will help you.
Happy Coding :)

Comment: but I'm using story board

Comment: @sam I also use storyboard but I haven't created the data pickers in storyboard if you like to use them from storyboard just pass the instance from storyboard to the init method instead of creating them in side init